# Gstreamer: xvimagesink internal error: can't allocate images

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I have the following simple gstreamer pipeline:

```
+--------+    +--------------+
| appsrc | -> |  vximagesink |
+--------+    +--------------+
```

In appsrc's "need data" callback I have the following lines:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gst::Memory> memory =
    Gst::Memory::create(static_cast<Gst::MemoryFlags>(0), ptr, size, 0, size);

Glib::RefPtr<Gst::Buffer> buffer = Gst::Buffer::create();
buffer->insert_memory(-1, std::move(memory));

buffer->set_pts(timestamp);
buffer->set_duration(gst_util_uint64_scale_int(1, GST_SECOND, 30));

srcapp->push_buffer(buffer);
```

Where 'ptr' is pre-allocated, and holds valid data.

According to the documentation, in this code, the allocated data will be wrapped inside a memory object, in turn is wrapped by the buffer object. But something here doesn't work, because the vximagesink sends an error event that says **"Internal error: can't allocate images"** (This happens when no pool is available for xvimagesink, but no pool is needed in this example).

The pipeline is built simply (I'm not showing the properties settings):

```
pipeline->add(appsrc)->add(sink);
appsrc->link(sink);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem recently and instead of posting new question I found out that this happens if you are using xvimagesink element without caps set to something that will tell how much space needs to be allocated. Look here:
https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-base/blob/master/sys/xvimage/xvimagesink.c#L1082
In my case after specifying caps filter between appsrc and sink (video/x-raw,width,height,format and framerate) it is running well.

Comment: Solution will be to set gst_app_src_set_caps, as soon as you will get sample in the new-sample callback in appsink.